# How can the replicator equation be forward invariant when payoffs are negative?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, game-theory, evolutionary-game-theory

Hi I'm self learning in game-theory and one of the most used equations is the replicator equation, which simulates how frequencies of a certain strategy change in a population of players.

$$\frac{dp_i}{dt}= p_i[\pi(e_i,p)-\pi(p,p)] $$

where $p_i$ is the proportion of individuals in the population using strategy $i$. $\pi(e_i,p)$ is the payoff to use strategy $i$ when population is its current state $p$. Lastly, $\pi(p,p)$ is the average payoff, a simple weighted average, summing the payoffs for each strategy, times their proportion in the population.

Many sources [(e.g.)](http://www.pnas.org/content/suppl/2014/07/10/1400823111.DCSupplemental/pnas.1400823111.sapp.pdf) say that this equation is forward invariant when $0<p_i<1 \space \forall i $. However, they put no constrain in the value of payoff. There is also no indication the authors are using some information of the function $\pi()$.

However, I can see an example where this is not true. Let $p_i$ is very small (say 0.01) and the payoff for strategy i is very small compared to the rest of the population $\pi(e_i,p)-\pi(p,p)= -100000$. $\frac{dp_i}{dt}$ and $p_i$ will become negative, no?

What am I missing? How can the replicatior equation be forward invariant?

Comment: The rate of change of the logarithm of $p_{i}$ will become negative, no?

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow.... Are you asking about $dlog(p_i)/dt$?

Comment: Cause your equation is $\frac{d\log{p_{1}}}{dt}=\pi(e_{i}, p)-\pi(p, p)$, so whenever the difference on the rhs is negative the rate of change of the log of $p_{i}$ is negative, thus it decreases with time, or I'm missing something?

Comment: Yes, I think your statement is correct. But let me see if I got the full picture: because the replicator equation can be converted to $\frac{d log p_i } {dt}=\pi(e_i,p)-\pi(p,p)$, $p_i$ will tend to 0, but never reach it, since it follows a logarithm function. Is that correct?

Comment: That is what i was thinking of